# Make main thread wait until all other threads done in IPhone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, ios4

I am working on threads in objective C for the first time in my coding experience. In my app i needs to download some assets in two threads. After completion of downloading i have to start my main thread which will make use of the downloaded assets in threads. So i wrote some code like this

```
NSThread *threadPlayer1 = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getPlayer1Assets) object:nil];
            
[threadPlayer1 start];
            
NSThread *threadPlayer2 = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getPlayer2Assets) object:nil];
            
[threadPlayer2 start];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(introducePlayer1) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I wrote waituntilDone to Yes but it waits until the first thread completes only.
so if i wants to wait untill all the two threads completed what should i do? can any one suggest with sample code snippets.

Comment: I think fundamentally, your thread architecture is broken here: Blocking your main thread renders it unresponsive to events whilst blocked.  Instead the pattern you should be using is one in which the completion notifications are posted to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest, would be to use [this](http://eng.alphonsolabs.com/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/). It's from Pulse Engeenering Blog. Spend a bit of time in it, until you grasp the idea.

As for your code. I guess you are doing this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(introducePlayer1) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

On the main thread. Read what is said about it on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specially the last sentence:

> wait A Boolean that specifies whether the current thread blocks until
>   after the specified selector is performed on the receiver on the main
>   thread. Specify YES to block this thread; otherwise, specify NO to
>   have this method return immediately.
>
> If the current thread is also the main thread, and you specify YES for
>   this parameter, the message is delivered and processed immediately.

Comment: The link is dead; this is a bad answer.

Comment: @GrahamPerks none of the links are dead dude. :S

Comment: I get "Safari can't find the server" for the http://eng.alphonsolabs.com link. Regardless, links can die and thus "link-to-answer" answers are fragile and poor form.